# Can I use ReactElement as useState argument?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm new in React and I wonder is using ReactElement as useState argument normal?
I try to do it and everything works fine. Is it anti-pattern or it's OK?
Unfortunately, I didn't find any information about it in documentation

```
const [infoBox, setInfobox] = useState<ReactElement|null>(null);
const catalogLoadedDataEmpty = useSelector(getCatalogLoadedDataEmptySelector);
const catalogHasErrors = useSelector(getCatalogHasErrorsSelector);
...
useEffect(() => {
    let infoBoxTitle;

    if (catalogLoadedDataEmpty) {
      infoBoxTitle = t('pages.Brands.errors.noResults.title');
    } else if (catalogHasErrors) {
      infoBoxTitle = errorsByErrorCode[EErrorCodes.UNRECOGNIZED_ERROR](t);
    } else {
      setInfobox(null);
      return;
    }

    setInfobox(<InfoBox
      className={catalogInfoBoxClassname}
      iconName={EInfoBoxIcon.error}
      title={infoBoxTitle}
      description={noResultsDescription}
    />);
}, [catalogLoadedDataEmpty, catalogHasErrors]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's easy to create bugs where you expect the page to update, but it doesn't, because you forgot to update the state. It's usually better to save data in state, and then use that data to render fresh elements on each render.

And in your case i'd go one step further: this shouldn't be a state variable at all. The values `catalogLoadedDataEmpty` and `catalogHasErrors` are enough to determine the desired output directly. You can thus remove the use effect, and in so doing get rid of the double-render that you currently have:

```
const catalogLoadedDataEmpty = useSelector(getCatalogLoadedDataEmptySelector);
const catalogHasErrors = useSelector(getCatalogHasErrorsSelector);

let infoBoxTitle;
if (catalogLoadedDataEmpty) {
  infoBoxTitle = t('pages.Brands.errors.noResults.title');
} else if (catalogHasErrors) {
  infoBoxTitle = errorsByErrorCode[EErrorCodes.UNRECOGNIZED_ERROR](t);
}

const infoBox = infoBoxTitle ? (
  <InfoBox
    className={catalogInfoBoxClassname}
    iconName={EInfoBoxIcon.error}
    title={infoBoxTitle}
    description={noResultsDescription}
  />
) : null
```